# Stretching an imageview, different on each screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have imageview with resolution of 430x871 in folders xxhdpi, xhdpi and hdpi. But when I run app, on 5" Xperia Z (xxhdpi) screen it works normally (1. picture) but on 4.7" Amazon Phone (xhdpi) it's smaller (2. picture). Altough when I run it on Amazon Fire HD 8.9 or 7 or 6, (all xdpi) it works too...

How can I stretch in on that Amazon Phone?

[image: Picture 1 (Xperia Z)]

[image: Picture 2 (Amazon Phone)]

Here is XML code of the Imageview:

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/matter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/matter"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

if aspect ratio is not important for you use:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

but if yes try this:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

and also change this:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: Yes, the aspect ratio matters, do I have to set adjustviewbounds on true or false?

Comment: according to Google docs : Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable. 
adjustViewBounds will not increase the size of the ImageView beyond the natural dimensions of the drawable. It will only shrink the view to maintain aspect ratio

Comment: personally I suggest you to use 3 images with your prefered dimentions  in these folders: drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xhdpi , drawable-hdpi and so on...

Comment: Yes, it would help, but there are over 20 images like this and it would be too big APK...

Comment: there is no way to solve this problem if aspect ratio is so important for you. I suggest you save them for web in photoshop and if it doesn't reduces the size of your app you can have different apks for different screen sizes.

Comment: and if my answer helps you please accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: @user3932494 How Come you want to respect the aspect ration and also stretch the image all the screen for all devices?!! there's no magic way to do that, you have two options, respect the aspect ratio or stretch your image

Comment: @Milad, so if the screen is hdpi, I have to set the image to that resolution and delete adjustviewbounds?

Comment: But why is it working on xhdpi tablet but not on xhdpi phone with same resolution as tablet?

Answer (score 0):

There's a property called :

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

inside ImageView tag.

Comment: When I do that, image is scaled only in width, not height

Comment: That's maybe because you have set your height to wrap_content

Comment: btw, the best solution would be to set a hardcoded height and create a 9-patch image in which you would only scale the left and write side of the image which is black, this way you won't need to set the scaletype, and the text won't get stretched in different devices and it certainly would occupy the whole screen just like you want